# How do I display the character for 1/2 in an NSString in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uilabel

I'm working on an application for iOS in which I would like to place the fractional value 1/2 as a single character within an NSString for use in an UILabel, is this possible?

Comment: Not really, I just want to know if there is a simple code that would display 1/2 in the space of a single character. No maths for it or anything, just I want to see 1/2 :)

Comment: As Paul states, this is not a duplicate of the above questions, he just wants to express the character of 1/2, so please don't vote to close this based on those.

Comment: How has this been closed as an exact duplicate? - it has nothing to do with the 'possible duplicate' link! Perhaps I was just bad at expressing the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the label's text property to the Unicode of 1/2:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",0x00bd];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use Mac OS's built-in character viewer: http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8164.html

So you can just do `label.text = @"½"`

Comment: 'Course it works. More often than not, the simplest solution is also the best: a raw string like this takes less time to be interpreted than, say, the `stringWithFormat` solution above, or any `sprintf`-like method.